# Can someone help me with the attack method in my fighter class

Tags: java, class, methods, instance, overloading

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5 {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
     Fighter myFighter, enemyFighter;
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     int num1, num2, num3;
     String str, another;
     System.out.println ("***  Fighter Game ***");

     do {
             System.out.println("Create your fighter (Type three integers + name):     ");
             num1 = console.nextInt();   num2 = console.nextInt();   num3     = console.nextInt();
             str = console.next();
             if (num1 + num2 + num3 == 10) {
                    myFighter = new Fighter (num1, num2, num3, str);
                   enemyFighter = new Fighter( );
                   enemyFighter.setName ("Enemy");
                   System.out.print( myFighter.getName()+"    ["+myFighter.getPower()+","+myFighter.getSpeed()+","+myFighter.getHeal()+"] ");
                   System.out.print( enemyFighter.getName()+"    ["+enemyFighter.getPower()+","+enemyFighter.getSpeed()+","+enemyFighter.getHeal()+"] ");
                   System.out.println();

                 int fights = 0;
                 boolean gameOver= false;
                 while (fights < 10  &&  !gameOver){
                     System.out.print("Fight[" + fights + "]: ");
                     myFighter.attack (enemyFighter);
                     myFighter.heal ();
                     enemyFighter.attack(myFighter);
                     enemyFighter.heal();
                     myFighter.printInfo();
                     enemyFighter.printInfo();
                     if (enemyFighter.isDead() ||     myFighter.isDead()) gameOver = true;
                     fights ++;
                     System.out.println();
                 }
                 if(myFighter.getHealth() > enemyFighter.getHealth())     System.out.println(" You Win");
                 else System.out.println("You Lost");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Play another fight (y/n)? ");
                another = console.next();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Inputs. The total of three     numbers should be 10.");
                another = console.next();
            }
        } while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
}







public class Fighter
{
public Fighter()
{

}


private int power = (int)(1 + Math.random()*5);
private int speed = (int)(1 + Math.random()*5);
private int heal = 10 - (power + speed);
private int health = 50;
private String name;

public Fighter (int num1, int num2, int num3, String str)
{
this.power = num1;
this.speed = num2;
this.heal = num3;
this.name = str;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public int getPower()
{
    return power;
}

public int getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

public int getHeal()
{
    return heal;
}

public int getHealth()
{
    return health;
}

public void setName(String newName)
{
    name = newName;
}

public void setPower(int newPower)
{
    power = newPower;
}

public void setSpeed(int newSpeed)
{
    speed = newSpeed;
}
public void setHeal(int newHeal)
{
    heal = newHeal;
}

public void setHealth(int newHealth)
{
    health = newHealth;
}

public boolean isDead()
{
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public void heal()
{
    int random =(int)(1+ Math.random()*10);

    if (random <= 3 && health <= 49)
    {
        health++;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

public void printInfo()
{
    System.out.print(name + "[" + health + "]       ");
}

public void attack(Fighter f)
{
    this.health = this.health - power;
    health = health - this.power;
}
}
```

The first group of code is the program for my assignment, the second one, the fighter     class, is what I am working on. The attack method is supposed to subtract the power of one     fighter from the health of another but all I can get them to do is subtract double their own     power from their own health. How do I set it up to have one fighters power subtracted from the     other fighters health and why is the overloaded method doubling everything that I do?

Do I not fully understand how overloaded methods work? do they double everything or is there something that I have written wrong and am I right in using this to try to get the new health values?

Comment: you don't use the param `f` inside your method `public void attack(Fighter f)` so your Fighter sort of fights with itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks like it is here:

```
public void attack(Fighter f)
{
  this.health = this.health - power;
  health = health - this.power;
}
```

This should be

```
public void attack(Fighter f)
{
  this.health = this.health - f.power;
  f.health = f.health - this.power;
}
```

Comment: so what you're saying is that the overloaded method is basically calling the other fighter f instead of this?

Comment: @user3363245 There's no overloading taking place in your code. Overloading a method means that there are multiple methods with the same name, but a different list of formal parameters. It's not relevant here. What I'm saying is that in your original version, all the fields accessed belong to `this` instance. If you don't qualify a field or method, `this` is implied. I fix it by specifying that the fields of other fighter instance should be used.

Comment: ok that makes sense, do you know why the attack method is subtracting double the power instead of the normal power value. Even if I just put System.out.print("hello") it will print out hellohello

Comment: In each round both fighters attack. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: yes both fighters attack but instead of the fighter's health being reduced by the opposing fighter's power the fighter's health is reduced by twice the opposing fighter's power, should I just divide by two or is there a "right" way to do it